# what is the meaning of obj-m: in Linux device driver Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver

I am very new to Linux device drivers.

In Makefile what is `obj-m`?

What is the difference between `obj-m` and `obj-m+`?

Comment: The target is called `obj-m`, the way to assign something to it may be `=`, `+=`, `:=`. This is syntax of `make` language. So, I recommend to read documentation about `make` first. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting

Comment: From the Linux kernel documentation for [obj-m](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#loadable-module-goals-obj-m): "$(obj-m) specifies object files that are built as kernel modules.". There isn't an `obj-m+`. The `+` is part of the `+=` operator to append to a variable. It can also be used to append subdirectories which will be entered recursively.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"obj-m := .o"

The kbuild system in kernel will build mod_name.o from mod_name.c 
After linking these files will get kernel module mod_name.ko.

The above line can be put in either a "Kbuild" file or a "Makefile."

When the module is built from multiple sources, an additional line is needed listing the files:

```
<module_name>-y := <src1>.o <src2>.o ...
```

For detailed info about this you can refer [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)